# How to sql select a product with two status?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a `Products` table

with `ProductId` and `StatusId` columns

How can i select all the products which have `StatusId` 1 and 2 (two rows) ?

Comment: i think the question is unclear. Maybe you can post some examples of your data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To select Products with both status (1,2):

[**Sql-Server fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae831/1)

```
SELECT ProductId 
FROM products
WHERE status IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY ProductId
HAVING COUNT(distinct status) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this query to get records for product having both the status 1 and 2

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ProductId 
FROM Products a, Products b 
WHERE a.ProductId = b.ProductId 
  AND a.StatusId = 1 
  AND b.StatusId = 2;
```

USING ANSI JOIN

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ProductId 
FROM Products a INNER JOIN Products b 
ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId 
WHERE a.StatusId = 1 
  AND b.StatusId = 2;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f9b0/1)

Comment: `a.StatusId = 1 AND b.StatusId = 2` it's impossible to select both! You need to use `IN` or replace it with `(a.StatusId = 1 OR b.StatusId = 2)`

Comment: a and b are different table and OP has mentioned that there are 2 rows for record so this condition will return true for that. Check this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f9b0/1

Comment: +1 Indeed, didn't noticed that! But it's a hell of a way to do it :P

Comment: I did it with a self join. other queries will also run if there are 2 records having status 1 as the are counting `HAVING COUNT(status) = 2` but Kaf has done it properly using `HAVING COUNT(distinct status) = 2`

Comment: @Meherzad Is there a reason why you are not using ANSI `JOIN` syntax but are joining in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: No specific reason. Just more comfortable using `WHERE` clause, gradually shifting to ANSI `JOIN` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.ProductId 
FROM Products a
INNER JOIN Products b ON a.ProductId = b.ProductId
WHERE a.StatusId IN (1, 2)
```

Comment: fyi: This query will select all the rows from table with status 1 or 2.